# Divide the data set by rows

Tags: python, pandas

## Given dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,4,5,6,8],
                  'b':[5,6,4,8,9,6],
                  'c':[6,3,3,7,8,4],
                  'd':[1,2,3,8,7,3],
                  'e':[3,2,4,4,6,2],
                  'f':[3,2,6,4,5,5]})
```

I want to divide/split df several parts (into 2,3,4.. n parts)

## Desired output:

df1 =

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f

0   1   5   6   1   3   3
1   2   6   3   2   2   2
```

df2 =

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f

2   4   4   3   3   4   6
3   5   8   7   8   4   4
```

df3 =

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f

4   6   9   8   7   6   5
5   8   6   4   3   2   5
```

## UPDATED

Real data has not equal dividable size!

real data `4351 rows × 3 columns`

Comment: Each subpart thus has two rows here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes. By If it is possible I want the logic not of How many rows, but number of new sub data frames. Here is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `qcut` to split. How you want to store it after is up to you

```
import pandas as pd
gp = df.groupby(pd.qcut(range(df.shape[0]), 3))  # N = 3

d = {f'df{i+1}': x[1] for i, x in enumerate(gp)}

d['df1']
#   a  b  c  d  e  f
#0  1  5  6  1  3  3
#1  2  6  3  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame can be evenly divided into `n` chunks:

```
n = 3
dfs = [df.loc[i] for i in np.split(df.index, n)]
```

`dfs` is a list containing 3 dataframes.

Comment: `dfs[0]` for example. If you want to splat this out: `df1, df2, df3 = dfs[:3]`

Comment: My data frame can not be divided into 3 parts `ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division` . This happens if n = 2

In case of n = 3 i get `ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division`

Comment: It cannot be split into 3 equal chunks. If you have 10 rows, how would you split them into 3 parts?

Comment: 3, 3 and 1 for example

Comment: They add up to only 7 rows. You can also play with `np.array_split`, which divide the 10 rows to 4, 3, 3

Comment: Yes `np.array_split` is a nice way to do this, much faster than `qcut`